# Rails view logic in controller producing hash/array instead of printing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Trying to do a summary "article" programatically, full of "newsitems" from the last 24 hours. For the moment, a submit button on a form points to `create_summary`, which gets you this inside the article controller:

```
def create_summary
  @article = Article.create!(
  headline: 'SUMMARY: Spain March 8, 2016',
  type_id: '27',
  status: 'published',
  body: Newsitem.last24.each do |newsitem|
    newsitem.slug
  end
  )
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :action => 'admin', notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
  end
end
```

It creates the new article okay, and `Newsitem.last24.each do` returns the correct number of newsitems, but as a hash or an array, instead of letting me do what you can normally do within a block. Here's the hash/array it returns:

```
[#<Newsitem id: 173, item: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...", source: "", created_at: "2016-03-07 16:15:46", updated_at: "2016-03-07 16:25:42", slug: "Test Draft Live Blog Update With A Photo. Please I...", url: "", main: nil, imagesource: "A place.", status: "published", caption: "A test video caption with some words.", article_id: 165, video: "w5zJU2UP-So">, #<Newsitem id: 159, item: "The former long-time Popular Party Mayor of Valenc...", source: "", created_at: "2016-03-07 22:47:33", updated_at: "2016-03-07 22:48:50", slug: "New Test Update With Image Long Headline", url: "", main: "Screen_Shot_2015-12-23_at_21.04.48.png", imagesource: "", status: "published", caption: "", article_id: nil, video: "">, #<Newsitem id: 174, item: "The former long-time Popular Party Mayor of Valenc...", source: "", created_at: "2016-03-08 09:00:34", updated_at: "2016-03-08 09:00:34", slug: "A Test Last 24 Update", url: "", main: nil, imagesource: "", status: "published", caption: "", article_id: nil, video: "">]
```

And what we can do in views and partials normally is:

```
<% Newsitem.last24.each do |newsitem| %>
 **<%= newsitem.slug.upcase %>:** <%= newsitem.item.truncate(265) %>
 (<%= link_to 'Read full update', newsitem %>)
<% end %>
```

…so that the body of the article is filled with a nice list of the newsitems from the last 24 hours. The logic and the queries work in a view, but I can't work out how to get the same stuff into the 'body' of the article via the controller.

**OPTION 2:**

Have also tried rendering a partial through the controller on `create_summary`. This almost works. The alternative code:

```
def summary_body
  render :partial => 'newsitems/last24'
end

def create_summary
  @article = Article.create!(
  headline: 'SUMMARY: Spain March 8, 2016',
  type_id: '27',
  status: 'published',
  body: summary_body
  )
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :action => 'admin', notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
  end
end
```

Still returns a hash, but at least some printing and formatting has taken place:

```
["              **TEST DRAFT LIVE BLOG UPDATE WITH A PHOTO. PLEASE IGNORE.:** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan neque ac leo varius, sit amet lobortis lectus posuere. Ut ut felis bibendum metus placerat rhoncus sit amet id enim. Integer eget metus in ligula bibendum blandit sed et justo. Cras cursus d...\n              (<a href=\"http://localhost:3000/articles/165-160227161454-spanish-congress-votes-219-131-against-pedro-sanchez-as-new-pm-in-second-vote#173\">Read full update</a>)\n              **NEW TEST UPDATE WITH IMAGE LONG HEADLINE:** The former long-time Popular Party Mayor of Valencia, Rita Barberá, denied during a press conference on Thursday morning that she had ever committed fraud during her time at City Hall. &quot;I have not contributed to, ordered or ever known about money laundering or h...\n              (<a href=\"/newsitems/159-160307234733-update-new-test-update-with-image-long-headline\">Read full update</a>)\n              **A TEST LAST 24 UPDATE:** The former long-time Popular Party Mayor of Valencia, Rita Barberá, denied during a press conference on Thursday morning that she had ever committed fraud during her time at City Hall. &quot;I have not contributed to, ordered or ever known about money laundering or h...\n              (<a href=\"/newsitems/174-160308100034-update-a-test-last-24-update\">Read full update</a>)\n"]
```

So the problem in this second version would be breaking up or parsing the formatted array in some way.

How do I get from A to B (in either case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally answered this question, which came up again, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045811/rails-why-can-i-send-a-single-record-attribute-via-controller-to-new-record-but).

You have to process the same array in a different way in the controller than you do in a view. Not sure why Rails works this way or if is something to do with MVC generally.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the `each` method on `Array` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns an proper `Array`. So you can't make operations like `array.element`, as `Arrays` are numbered indexed data structures, so you access with something like `array[0].upcase`.
What you can do however is set the body to receive:

```
 body: Newsitem.last24
```

This way, `body` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so you can iterate on it, and use the hash/object notation you like.

Comment: Hmmm, closer, what do I do with it then? Where do I iterate through them? Reducing it to just `body: Newsitem.last24` returns `#<Newsitem::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa1ab2ee808>` in the body of the created article.

Comment: @MatthewBennett Yes. In your view you can do `body.each do |newsitem|`. Each `newsitem` now is a `NewsItem` model object, so you can use `newsitem.slug.upcase` and etc.

Comment: As part of a conditional within the article view?